# ¿Como convertir un archivo XLSX a CSV con PHP?

Tags: php, php7, php5

Tengo que pasar un archivo .xlsx a .csv

```
if ($extension == "xls" or $extension == "xlsx") {
         echo "Convertir a CSV"
         $arc_csv = $this->convertirArchivo($request,$file); 
}else{
         echo "No es necesaria la conversion";
}
```

Primero verifico la extensión del archivo que voy a subir y le indico que si es un .xlsx o .xls se debe pasar a una función que me ayude a cambiar su formato.

No se si hay alguna libreria o con php puro se pueda realizar dicho cambio

Answer (score 4):

Siga los pasos a continuación para convertir XLS a CSV.

Paso 1). Descargue la biblioteca PHPExcel de Github y extráigala .

Paso 2). Incluya PHPExcel.php en su archivo.

```
include 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
```

Paso 3)   Abra el archivo de Excel con PHPExcel IOFactory

```
   $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel5");
    //Excel5 is the type of excel file.

    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);   
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("input.xls");
```

Lectores de archivos admitidos:

> Excel5 -> formato de archivo entre Excel Versión 95 a 2003
>   Excel2003XML -> formato de archivo para Excel 2003 Excel2007 ->
>   formato de archivo para Excel 2007

Podemos obtener el tipo de lector de archivos automáticamente usando

```
$fileType=PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify("input.xls");
```

Paso 4) Crear un escritor de archivos CSV

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
```

Paso 5) Guardar XLS como CSV

```
$objWriter2007->save("output.csv");
```

Poniendo todo junto: a continuación se muestra la función para convertir XLS a CSV en PHP

```
<?php
require_once('PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');

//Usage:
convertXLStoCSV('input.xls','output.csv');

function convertXLStoCSV($infile,$outfile)
{
    $fileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($infile);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);

    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);   
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($infile);    

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
    $objWriter->save($outfile);
}

?>
```

Nota: Puede usar la misma función para convertir XLSX a CSV. Puede convertir XLS a PDF, XLS a CSV o XLS a HTML cambiando los tipos de lector y escritor de archivos.

Solución de problemas: a veces la conversión falla debido a problemas de memoria. Puede aumentar el límite de memoria agregando la siguiente línea al comienzo del archivo.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2000M'); //for 2GB

//For no limits
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
```